# How to convert joda dateTime to string in swagger

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, objectmapper

In swagger-core version 1.3.x, we were able to control the rendering of DateTime by using this code as also mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/overriding-models#in-java-with-swagger-core-version-13x) :

```
import com.wordnik.swagger.converter.*;

String jsonString = "{" +
"  \"id\": \"Date\"," +
"  \"properties\": {" +
"    \"value\": {" +
"      \"required\": true," +
"      \"description\": \"Date in ISO-8601 format\"," +
"      \"notes\": \"Add any notes you like here\"," +
"      \"type\": \"string\"," +
"      \"format\": \"date-time\"" +
"    }" +
"  }" +
"}";
OverrideConverter converter = new OverrideConverter();
converter.add("java.util.Date", jsonString);

ModelConverters.addConverter(converter, true);
```

But this solution doesn't work in swagger 2.0 as I am not able to find OverrideConvertor in swagger 2.0.

At present the date Time from my code is being rendered as below :

```
LocalDateTime {
chronology (Chronology, optional),
weekOfWeekyear (integer, optional),
weekyear (integer, optional),
monthOfYear (integer, optional),
yearOfEra (integer, optional),
yearOfCentury (integer, optional),
centuryOfEra (integer, optional),
millisOfSecond (integer, optional),
millisOfDay (integer, optional),
secondOfMinute (integer, optional),
minuteOfHour (integer, optional),
hourOfDay (integer, optional),
year (integer, optional),
dayOfMonth (integer, optional),
dayOfWeek (integer, optional),
era (integer, optional),
dayOfYear (integer, optional),
fields (Array[DateTimeField], optional),
fieldTypes (Array[DateTimeFieldType], optional),
values (Array[integer], optional)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to add your custom converters to swagger 1.5. But these are workarounds for your use case:

You can create a `Model` and replace it in the generated swagger object, before converting it to Json.

```
ModelImpl m = new ModelImpl()
          .description("LocalDateTime in ISO format")
          .format("ISO DateTime")
          .name("DateTime")
          .type("string");
Response response = getListingJsonResponse(app, context, sc, headers, uriInfo);
Swagger swagger = (Swagger) response.getEntity();
swagger.getDefinitions().put("LocalDateTime", m);
```

That will replace the definition of `LocalDateTime` with a string type model.

The other way will be to iterate through the definitions, and wherever you see the reference type to LocalDateTime, replace that with a string type:

```
Map<String, Model> definitions = swagger.getDefinitions();
  for(Map.Entry<String, Model> e : definitions.entrySet()){
    Map<String, Property> propertyMap = e.getValue().getProperties();
    for(String key : propertyMap.keySet()){
      Property value = propertyMap.get(key);
      if(value.getType().equals("ref") && ((RefProperty) value).getSimpleRef().equals("LocalDateTime")){
        propertyMap.put(key, new StringProperty("LocalDateTime in ISO format")
                .example("dd-mm-yyyy")
                .pattern("pattern")
                .description("ISO format string"));
      }
    }
  }
```

As of now I am unaware of any other cleaner way to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

Swagger has a mapping for `DateTime` and not `LocalDateTime`. So you can also consider moving your types to `DateTime` if that works for you.